# Memory limit per queue in ActiveMQ

Tags: activemq-classic

What does the `memoryLimit` mean in the below configuration?

```xml
<policyEntry queue="TEST.QUEUE" memoryLimit="25mb"/>
```

As per [the documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/per-destination-policies):

> This memory limit is subordinate to the system level memory limit, as specified by the `<systemUsage>`/`<memoryUsage>` attribute. There is no default for this value; it simply acts as a child to the overall broker memory until the broker memory is exhausted.

Is it recommended to set this value? In which scenario this would be useful? Please explain.

Answer (score 0):

This means that the broker will limit the amount of memory used for messages in the queue to 25mb. The broker splits producers and consumers 60/40, so you get the 25 mb is split

15mb for producers
10mb for consumers

This allows you to manage 'noisy neighbor' problems and supports multi-tenancy in the broker. In situations where apps that use large messages may impact performance of other queues in the broker. If you have small messages (ie 4k to 8k) its usually not an issue.

However, when you start getting larger messages (512k to 10mb) the memory requirements start adding up, as the broker defaults to loading 200 messages at a time for consumers. For example, 200 messages x 10mb = 2gb of RAM for one queue -- and that may cause undesirable impact to other queues.

The 'subordinate' part means the systemUsage is the broker-wide max. The 25mb means a queue can get 'up to 25mb, as long as there is room under the systemUsage memoryLimit'. If you have 100 queues and only 1.4 GB for memoryUsage, not all queues may see the full 25mb available to them at all times.